# How do I open a project that I've downloaded earlier?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

My friend sent me a project that he did before, and I don't know how can I open it. I know how I can do it by opening all the classes but I want to open the whole project including the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look for the `.sln` file which represents the solution and open this one in Visual Studio. Or if it contains only a single project look for the `.csproj` file.

Comment: It do nothing, I'm clicking on it and it isn't opening anything

Comment: @Rich Porter, I just saw your other comment about the rar file. You will have to uncompress it first. You could use [WinRar](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm) for this.

Comment: @Rich Porter, yes I mean extract. So if you already have extracted it you could run Visual Studio and try to locate and open the .sln or .csproj file you have extracted.

Comment: @Rich: You'll need to have Visual Studio installed on your computer to be able to do much of anything with the code. If you're just trying to read it (rather than compile it), you can look for files with a `.cs` extension (those are the C# code files) and open them in Notepad. But you really should [grab a copy of Visual Studio Express free from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-csharp-express), if you don't already have a a version.

Comment: @Darin, hey again, I'll upload the screenshot, I had to download XNA 4.0 and Visual 2010, I managed to open the file with the .sln using the visual studio 2010, but I can't debug/compile the code.

Comment: @Rich Porter, please start a new question. The comments section is not good for this kind of discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Open .Proj file if it is a project.If your friend sent you a website then open it using open website in visual studio menu option. select parent folder of website to open

Comment: My friend sent me .rar file where is the .Proj located at?

Comment: extract your rar file than find the .proj or .sln file to open

Comment: do you have installed visual studio?